# Moved row to column CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to programming so can anyone tell me how can I moved this box next to another box? i want to make 3 column, here's some illustration hopefully helpful

[image]

this is my **demo**:

```css
.product__sidebar__view__item {
  height: 190px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; //i've change all of this but seems doesn't work
}

.product__sidebar__view__item h5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px 0 20px;
}

.product__sidebar__view__item h5 a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<section class="product spad">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="sidebar_product">
                        <div class="product__sidebar__view">
                            <div class="section-title">
                                <h5>Main Menu</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <div class = "product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix month week" data-setbg="/assets/2.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="/billing">Survey</a></h5> 
                                </div>
                                 <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix month week" data-setbg="/assets/1.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Actor Mapping</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix week years" data-setbg="/assets/4.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Political Text Analysis</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix years month" data-setbg="/assets/4.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Social Media Network Analysis</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix years month" data-setbg="/assets/3.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Media Monitoring</a></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>        
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyone knows how to do it?
Thank you everyone!

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, please let us know the version or add a cdjns link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```css
.product__sidebar__view__item {
  height: 190px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; //i've change all of this but seems doesn't work
}

.product__sidebar__view__item h5 {
  bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px 0 20px;
}

.product__sidebar__view__item h5 a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.column {
  display: grid; 
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  }
```

```html
<section class="product spad">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="sidebar_product">
                        <div class="product__sidebar__view">
                            <div class="section-title">
                                <h5>Main Menu</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                                <div class = "product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix month week" data-setbg="/assets/2.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="/billing">Survey</a></h5> 
                                </div>
                                 <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix month week" data-setbg="/assets/1.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Actor Mapping</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix week years" data-setbg="/assets/4.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Political Text Analysis</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix years month" data-setbg="/assets/4.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Social Media Network Analysis</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix years month" data-setbg="/assets/3.jpg">
                                    <h5><a href="#">Media Monitoring</a></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>        
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is the exact things i want, but when i try it there's all box in one row, could i make it only 3?

Comment: yeah if you want to make it 3 use display:grid, grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; that should do it.

Comment: .product__sidebar__view {
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 display:grid, 
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
} 
like that?

Comment: @JacobSeptianusWijaya look above sample. I edited the code for you. all divs are under this .coloumn class you have. Let me know if that's what you are looking at. that's 3 at the top and 2 at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add row class to column div and col-4 to children divs, like this:

```
<div class="column row">
    <div class="col-4 product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix month week" data-setbg="/assets/2.jpg">
        <h5><a href="/billing">Survey</a></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix month week" data-setbg="/assets/1.jpg">
        <h5><a href="#">Actor Mapping</a></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix week years" data-setbg="/assets/4.jpg">
        <h5><a href="#">Political Text Analysis</a></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix years month" data-setbg="/assets/4.jpg">
        <h5><a href="#">Social Media Network Analysis</a></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix years month" data-setbg="/assets/3.jpg">
        <h5><a href="#">Media Monitoring</a></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

im usually use like this on BS

seems like u put all img in one col

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <p class="margin-padding">111</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <p class="margin-padding">222</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <p class="margin-padding">333</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

or using **Flex** can do like this
CSS:

```
.displayFlex{display:flex;}
.flex1{flex:1;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="displayFlex">
    <p class='flex1'>111</p>
    <p class='flex1'>222</p>
    <p class='flex1'>333</p>
</div>
```